# Find in which row of a tableView is a CollectionView

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, uicollectionview

I'm asking for your help because I blocked with something in my Swift App.
I would like to parse an array with some meals.
My array is the next one:

```
let meals_list: [[String]] = [
                                 ["breakfast", "snack_1", "pre_intra_post", "lunch", "snack_2", "diner"], 
                                 ["breakfast", "snack_1", "lunch", "snack_2", "diner"]
                             ]
```

As you can see, there are 6 items in the first part, and 5 items in the second one.

These meals are going to be displayed in a horizontal CollectionView.

Each CollectionView needs to be in a table view.

So, I would like to create 6 cards in my first collection view
And 5 cards in my second collection view.

Here is how I manage everything

```
//Manage meals content
    func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, numberOfItemsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        if section == 0{
            return 6
        } else {
            return 5
        }
    }

    func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell {

        let cell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCell(withReuseIdentifier: "collection_cell", for: indexPath) as! Meal_vc_cell

        return cell
    }



    //Manage day type content (train/rest)
    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        return 2
    }

    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
        let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "food_plan_cell", for: indexPath) as! FoodPlanCell

        if (indexPath.row == 0){
            cell.meals_day_type.text = "Vos repas les\r\njours d'entraînement".uppercased()
        } else {
            cell.meals_day_type.text = "Vos repas les\r\njours de Repos".uppercased()
        }

        return cell
    }

    private func tableView(tableView: UITableView,
        willDisplayCell cell: UITableViewCell,
        forRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) {

        guard let tableViewCell = cell as? FoodPlanCell else { return }

        tableViewCell.setCollectionViewDataSourceDelegate(dataSourceDelegate: self, forRow: indexPath.row)
    }
```

Comment: Is you collection view is outside of tableview or it's the part of tableview cell

Comment: @RakeshMandloi it is in the tableview cell

Comment: so your collection view delegate and data source should be configure inside table cell class not inside the viewcontroller. and pass you array of meal inside tableview cellforrowatindexpath and for specific index so you can easily separate out. you meal array and you can easily create view with diffrent size of meals.

Comment: @RakeshMandloi Thank you I'll try it and come back to you ASAP

Comment: What exactly do you have in your UICollectionViewCell?

Answer (score 1):

```
 func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell {

    let cell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCell(withReuseIdentifier: "collection_cell", for: indexPath) as! Meal_vc_cell

    cell.meal.text = meals_list.[indexPath.section][indexPath.item]

    return cell
}
```

Comment: doesn't work
by the way, indexPath.section always returns 0

Comment: You have more than one section, I don’t know why it would return 0 only